# how my browser know to put in placeholder attribute the value of the Client country?

Tags: php, html

If I have an international website and I have two clients:

1. client from Spain.
2. client from Israel.

I want the placeholder will be match for the client user.

The pseudo-code is:

```
if (client_from_israel)
  HTML CODE: <input type="text" placeholder="israel">
else
  HTML CODE: <input type="text" placeholder="spain">
```

How can I write it to work and display at the web browser? 
I think I will need to use php to do it.

I know its a LONG answer but if you don't have the power to write the code  just tell me what to do in general.

Comment: I think would be better to use `<select>` in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the user's IP address through $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] and then use some geotargeting class to translate it to a country.

I found a good [tutorial](http://www.blogstorm.co.uk/geotargeting-with-php/) on this subject. You can of course use a [free PHP geotargeting](http://tutorialfeed.net/development/geo-targeting-with-php) class for your project